# whether the Facebook API can return the set of apps that each friend has registered with (connected to with Facebook Connect)

Tags: android, facebook

Which Facebook API can return the set of apps/games that each friend has registered with?  (Connected to with Facebook Connect.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get that information unless you are the admin of every app you are interested in.

if you are an admin you can use some FQL to check that user is connected to that app

Edit - this is the fql "SELECT is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid=$fbu"